# EAFP coding style in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am learning shell script to facilitate my routine on computer.
In python, there's EAFP style to handle exceptions.

```
    >>> while True:
    ...     try:
    ...         x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    ...         break
    ...     except ValueError:
    ...         print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
```

Is there such a style in shell script?

Comment: How would you model an exception in Posix shell??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash doesn't have any kind of exception (nor does any other standard shell, to my knowledge).

Instead, we use the exit status, and chain commands accordingly

```
until test "$x" -le 0 || test "$x" -ge 0 2>/dev/null
do read -p "Please enter a number: " x
done
```